# nextjs add dynamic classNames with static classNames

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, jsx

I have just started with nextjs. To add the CSS class names dynamically this is what I am doing

```
<div className={selected? [styles.list,styles.half].join(" ") : styles.list}>
```

Now `styles.list` is the common in both if/else.

I tried

```
<div className={styles.list} className={selected? styles.half : ''}>
```

but this shows

```
JSX elements can not have multiple atrributes with same name
```

is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you can't have multiple attributes with the same name, in this instance `className`.

Comment: yes, but is there any way to do the same?

Comment: Maybe something like this? `className={\`${styles.list} ${selected ? styles.half : ''}\`}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you could try the following syntax :

```
className={`${styles.list} ${selected ? styles.half : ''}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
<div className={`${styles.list} ${selected? styles.half : ''}`}>
```